# Match all the letters in string

Tags: java, matcher

I am trying to find out that if my string contains all the letters from a to z & A to Z. I tried below: but it will return true if it has `aA`. I am looking for all the 52 letters i.e. if string have all 52 letters then only it will return true else false by using Pattern and matcher.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String s = sc.nextLine();
s=s.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
System.out.println(s);
// String input = "[a-zA-Z]+";
String input = "\\w+";
System.out.println(input);
Pattern pr = Pattern.compile(input);
Matcher m =pr.matcher(s);
if(m.matches()){
    System.out.println("pangram");
} else {
    System.out.println("non-pangram");
}
```

We can solve this by other ways, but I am trying to solve it by only using Pattern and matcher.

Comment: The regular expression you are looking for would be realöy complex. Is a loop allowed so you can check multiple times or does it have to be one expression and one matcher? Your expression matches one or more characters of the range a-zA-Z and the next expression matches one or more words so this will not work at all.

Comment: Regular expressions are not meant to solve this kind of problem. If you would succeed it would result in unmaintainable code.

Comment: Fuzzzel, is it possible if loop is allowed here?

Comment: Famous quote from Jamie Zawinski: "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think 'I know, I'll use regular expressions.' Now they have two problems."

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see if all 52 upper- and lower-case letters are present in a given input string, you can't use a regular expression. It simply cannot do something like that.

If the list of characters that *must* be present is dynamic, you can use this method:

```
private static boolean containsAllOf(String input, String alphabet) {
    boolean[] found = new boolean[alphabet.length()];
    int foundCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        char ch = input.charAt(i);
        int idx = alphabet.indexOf(ch);
        if (idx >= 0 && ! found[idx]) {
            found[idx] = true;
            if (++foundCount == found.length)
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

E.g. use it like this:

```
containsAllOf("abc", "abcdef")                  // returns false
containsAllOf("dfu hadkf kojuhoeuaf", "abcdef") // returns false
containsAllOf("bad fed", "abcdef")              // returns false
containsAllOf("bad fec", "abcdef")              // returns true
```

Performance can be improved if you specifically want to check the entire 52 upper- and lower-case letters of the *English* alphabet.

```
private static boolean containsAllOfAlphabet(String input) {
    boolean[] found = new boolean[52];
    int foundCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        char ch = input.charAt(i);
        int idx = (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z' ? ch - 'a' :
                   ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z' ? ch - 'A' + 26 : -1);
        if (idx >= 0 && ! found[idx]) {
            found[idx] = true;
            if (++foundCount == found.length)
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

---

**UPDATE** If you *want* to use a pattern matcher, here is one way.

Start by sorting all the characters of the input string, then use a pattern matcher to eliminate all non-letters and duplicate letters. If the length of the result is 52, then all letters are present.

Of course, a [pangram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pangram) normally don't consider uppercase and lowercase letters to be different, so calling `toLowercase()` and checking for length 26 may be more correct:

```
String input = "Pack my box with five dozen liquor jugs.";

char[] buf = input.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
Arrays.sort(buf);
boolean pangram = (new String(buf).replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]|([a-zA-Z])\\1+", "$1").length() == 26);
System.out.println(pangram ? "pangram" : "non-pangram");
```

Comment: Thank you Andreas, i am looking with pattern matchers. even you can use Set to determine all 52 letters. check my answer by using Set.

Comment: Thanks Andreas, great :)

Answer (score -1):

I have used set and putting the every character(ASC) in it, as Set only contains the unique values so I am checking size == 26 for all characters. use if(put>=97 && put<=122 ) before adding.

```
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s= sc.nextLine();
    Set<Integer> h = new HashSet<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            int put = (int)s.charAt(i);
            if(put>=97 && put<=122 ) {
                h.add(put);
            }
            if(put>=65 && put<=90 ) {
                h.add(put);
            }
        }
        if(h.size()==52)
            System.out.println("all 52");
        else
            System.out.println("missing");
```

Comment: Please also add an explanation.

Comment: `if (size==26) print(52)` Huh?  What if text contains punctuation characters?

Comment: sorry, my bad i.e pangram and non-pangram. used for testing

Comment: Ursinus TheStrong, i have used set and putting the every character(ASC) in it, as Set only contains the unique values so i am checking size == 26 for all characters. use if(put>=97 && put<=122 ) before adding. thank you

Comment: Add the explanation in the answer dude